# Can we run Scheduler class through another org?

Tags: rest-api, scheduled-apex

I have a issue ,I have a source org and a target org ,i run a scheduler class from source org and it send data to taget org .Now i want to reschedule source org Scheduler class from target org .
How can i do that ????
Is it possible ???

Answer (score 0):

I would think about writing a @RestSource class in your target org, then implementing there a @Post method which gets the data from the source org.

The rest API callout is called in the source target but the post method via the target org will be invoked and there you can try to call any schedulable class with the sent target org data.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm

Does it meet your requirements?

Comment: Thanks for reply @ Derminal  ,  i have done all the things ,i wrote  callout class in source which is working fine . i scheduled this class by scheduler apex ,which also working fine . now i have a requirement that i need to run this scheduler class through my target org for different time . plz tell me how can i do that

Comment: I hope I understood you, if yes, you can perform the opposed way. Write a @RestResource POST method in your source org. And then your target org will make the rest API callout to trigger the source org with relevant data regarding the schedular.